# How to read file line by line using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Source file is present in below manner:-

> abc
>
> dfc
>
> adbc

I am using below code to print the each line in the file.

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type input.txt') do (

set line=%%a
echo %line%
)
```

but the output is

> adbc
>
> adbc
>
> adbc

What to do? Required output is:

> abc
>
> dfc
>
> adbc

Comment: Why would you put powershell down if you werent looking for powershell help?

Comment: Going to assume you don't understand what the English word **pause** means.  Open up a cmd prompt and type: `pause /?`.  If you are going to assign the FOR variable to an environmental variable, then you need to use delayed expansion to reference the variable. Read this: https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Comment: @Squashman:- i have added this `setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` in the script still the same.

Comment: I see you didn't read all of that link I provided.  So I will give you a fish today. `echo !line!`

Comment: @Squashman:- super ! it is working. thank you

Comment: @Squashman sorry, I didn't realise you replied.

Comment: Simply do `echo %%a` and you get what you want, there is no need to assign the line string to an interim variable `line`...

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specifically need to manipulate the line or save the content of the last line in a variable there is absolutely no need to use a `For` loop:

```cmd
Type input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

@Squashman provided the answer really, but here it is written out:

```
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type input.txt') do (
set line=%%a

echo !line!
)
```

Comment: There's no need to iterate over the output of `type`. `for` can read the file just fine.